# Integrating $\frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to understand how to integrate:
$$\frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}$$
I tried substituting $t$ as $\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}$, but I can't get an answer that way, and I don't know any other way to integrate other than by parts, which I don't think can be used here. How should I integrate this?

Comment: Let $x=a\sec(t)$.

Comment: For a magic substitution, let $u=x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I've got the correct antiderivative using the method in the answers.. but I'm stuck with this magic substitution.

Comment: We have $du=(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}})\,dx=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\,dx$. So $\frac{du}{u}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\,dx$. Integrate. We get $\ln u+C$.

Comment: Brilliant! That's very interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}} \text{ and }\int\frac{da}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}.
$$
Of course it is conventional to assume the former is meant, but writing $dx$ or $da$ makes that explicit.

Both of them beg for trigonometric substitutions.

Assuming $dx$ and not $da$, then
\begin{align}
x^2-a^2 & = (a\sec\theta)^2 -a^2 = a^2(\sec^2\theta-1)=a^2\tan^2\theta \\[8pt]
a^2-x^2 & = a^2 - (a\sin\theta)^2 = a^2(1-\sin^2\theta)=a^2\cos^2\theta \\[8pt]
a^2+x^2 & = a^2 + (a\tan\theta)^2 = a^2(1+\tan^2\theta)=a^2\sec^2\theta
\end{align}
(The third one above should be used regardless of whether it's $dx$ or $da$, but interchanging $dx$ and $da$ corresponds to interchanging the roles of the first two equalities above.)

**All three of these use Pythagorean identities from trigonometry.**

Comment: How can we substitute $asec\theta$ for x?

Comment: Note that it is also possible to use hyperbolic functions for the first of these substitutions because $\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2x =1$ has the same form as $\sec^2 x-\tan^2 x =1$

Comment: @ABajaj : In the expression $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$, the variable $x^2$ necessarily takes values $\ge a^2$ (unless we bring in complex numbers, which opens a can of worms that is not mentioned here).  So $|x/a|\ge1$, and thus there is some value of $\theta$ for which $x/a = \sec\theta$.  If you have an objection to that, can you say what it is? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the substitution $\underbrace{x = a\sec \theta}_{\Large \theta = \operatorname{arcsec}\left(\frac xa\right)}\implies dx = a\sec\theta \tan\theta$

And recall that $\tan^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta - 1$.

See this link for an outline of dealing with [integrals containing $x^2 - a^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trig_substitution#Integrals_containing_x2_.E2.88.92_a2) where the variable with respect to which we are integrating is $x$ (i.e., where $dx$ accompanies your function under the integral sign: such as $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

From a table of derivatives, $\frac{d}{dx}\left[\cosh^{-1}x\right]=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$.

And by a simple change of scale
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}=\int\frac{d(at)}{\sqrt{(at)^2-a^2}}=\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}=\cosh^{-1}t=\cosh^{-1}\frac xa.$$

Comment: How is this answer the same as the other one?

Comment: You can start from $x=\cosh y=\frac{e^y+e^{-y}}2$ and invert it to get the formula for $\cosh^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\text{Integrating} &\int \frac {1\cdot dx}{\sqrt {(x^2-a^2)}}\\\\
\text{Put x} &= a \cdot \cosh (\theta)\\
\Rightarrow \theta &= \cosh^{-1} \left(\frac {x}{a} \right)\\
\text{Therefore}\\ dx &= a \cdot \sinh(\theta) \cdot d\theta\\\\
\text{Now}\\
&\int \frac {a \cdot \sinh (\theta) \cdot d \theta}{\sqrt {a^2\cdot(\cosh^2(\theta)-1)}}\\\\
&\Rightarrow \frac {a \cdot \sinh (\theta) \cdot d \theta}{\sqrt {a^2\cdot \sinh ^2(\theta)}}\\
&\Rightarrow \int \frac{a \cdot \sinh (\theta) \cdot  d\theta}{a \cdot \sinh (\theta)}\\
&\Rightarrow \int 1 \cdot d\theta\\
&\Rightarrow \theta + c\\
&\Rightarrow \cosh^{-1} \left(\frac {x}{a} \right) +c
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

May be we can remark that $\cosh(\text{argcosh}(x))=x$ and so by derivation, $$\text{argcosh}'(x)=\frac{1}{\sinh(\text{argcos}(x))}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

I let you generalise the case where we have $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$

Answer (score 2):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx$

Let $\left(x^2-a^2\right)=y^2\;,$ Then $\displaystyle 2xdx = 2ydy\Rightarrow \frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{x}$

Now Using Ration and Proportion, We Get $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{d(x+y)}{(x+y)}$

So Integral $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{dx}{y} = \int\frac{d(x+y)}{(x+y)} = \ln \left|x+y\right|+C=\ln \left|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right|+C$

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but using ratios and proportions here seems a bit odd?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most far-fetched solution I can think of
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}=\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+x}{x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx=\int\frac{1+\frac x{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx=\ln(\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+x).$$
(The last integrand is of the form $\frac{f'}f$.)

Comment: Why do you call this far fetched?

Comment: Because nothing tells you that introducing the expression $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+x$ will yield such a nice simplification. A rabbit pulled out of a hat.

Comment: So... how did you think of it? (It's the same suggestion Andre Nicolas suggested)

Comment: Just by cheating (looking at the solution). Anyway, I also recognized the derivative of the $argch$ function (a close cousin of $arcsin$) for which the closed formula is known.

Comment: I've been searching, but I haven't found anything about argch. What is it?

Comment: The inverse hyperbolic cosine. It is also denoted as arccosh.

Comment: Is the usage of argch common?

Comment: Do you mean the function or the notation ?

Comment: I've seen the function before: I mean the notation argch rather than arcosh or $cosh^-1$.

Comment: I don't know what's the preferred usage. The inverse hyperbolic functions are often prefixed with arg (argument) instead of arc.

Comment: Why is arcosh closely related to arcsin? I know that $sinh = -isinx$.

Comment: $-i\sin ix$. And $(\arcsin x)'=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. All are special cases of the complex exponential/logarithm.

Comment: That's very interesting.

Comment: See also [Inverse hyyperbolic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function) at Wikipedia @ABajaj